# How can I find out the levels that I missed Bonus Stages in?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-2

In order to 100% beat Donkey Kong Country 2, you need to obtain all (75) Kremcoins by completing all the bonus stages hidden in all the levels throughout the game. Is it possible to know which levels have bonus stages that I missed?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - the clue is rather subtle. If you have found all the bonus stages, the level will end in a "!" on the map screen. Therefore, you can tell which levels still have bonus stages to complete by the absence of a "!".

For example if you complete all the bonus stages in the first level, "PIRATE PANIC", the title will become "PIRATE PANIC!"

Before completing all bonus stages:
[image]

After completing all bonus stages:
[image]

Comment: To add to this, if you obtain all the Kremcoins within a world e.g. Gankplank Galleon, the world title will have the "!". Likewise for the DK coin.