# How do I check which bonus rooms I've found in DKC?

Tags: donkey-kong-country

After beating King K. Rool in Donkey Kong Country (SNES), Cranky Kong bragged to me that there were bonus rooms I hadn't found. I want to find the missing bonus rooms, but I don't know what levels to check.

Is there a way to check which levels have bonus rooms I still need to find?

Comment: The same pattern is followed in DKC2:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/355261/how-can-i-find-out-the-levels-that-i-missed-bonus-stages-in/355262#355262

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Level names will have an exclamation point (**!**) if you have visited every bonus room in the level.

[image: Completed DKC1 level]